# Moving Zip Files (Android Studio Java)

Tags: java, android, assets, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have a Mapnik.ZIP file that I manually placed into my phone's internal SD in the OSMDroid folder and my mobile application grabs the .PNG images to use them as tiles on my MapView.

Where should I place this .ZIP file in my project and what type of codes should I be looking into to move this ZIP file to the OSMDroid file automatically, under the assumption that this project/application is something that's downloaded right off the Play Store?

Asset Manager? Should I store the ZIP in my Assets folder then copy the file to my SD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes ,you can place them in asset folder ,and oncreate method of main activity ,you can copy them to sdcard/osmdroid folder if it is not there already (can check with file size and file name).